# "mv" versus "cp" in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cp, mv

I am attempting to make a script that will be able to load up some settings and files to a board.  Basically I will plus a flash drive into the board click on the script. The script will then copy/move some files to replace old ones that are out of date.  An example of this would be me replacing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` with a new one for different repositories.  Is it better to copy or move a file to this location to replace it?  I will also be installing apache2 in this script then moving over directories to the `www` and `cgi-bin`.  Is it better to copy or move directories?  I will also be changing permissions.

Basically my question is, is it better to move `mv` or copy `cp` files and directories when dealing with bash scripting?

Comment: Have you looked at rsync as an alternative to mv or cp? If yo're trying to keep folders up to date, this would be your best bet as it'll only replace files/folders that actually have had changes made to them.

Comment: @amanthethy It is not keeping them up to date.  The script is to load files and what not on the board autonomously when creating a clean board.  It is a pain in the ass to type up an interfaces file each time.

Comment: ah. Makes sense. Its just in the OP you mention, "The script will then copy/move some files to replace old ones that are out of date", so I assumed your were making a backup stick of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Move if you only need it in the target path, copy if you need it in both locations.** There's no inherent "insecurity" to `mv` or `cp`, and you'll be needlessly adding complexity (and extremely likely bugs) to your scripts if you start trying to implement your own `mv`.

For special cases there may be more suitable tools than either. For example, if you want to change owner or mode when copying there's the `install` tool which does that in one line rather than three.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In certain (usually rare) situations you should cp the file to a temporary name **on the target filesystem**, then mv it to it's final name, as the mv operation is atomic on a journaled file system.  If there is any chance the application will try to read this file while you are replacing it, do this.

You specified that you are transferring the file from a different filesystem (flash drive).  In this case mv is doing an implicit cp && rm.  If you go back 20+ years mv didn't even support this, but there is no reason to be stuck in history.

Comment: So basically `mv` is saving a step?

Comment: I think you mean "atomic", not "autonomous".

Comment: Yes, I noticed this behavior: "mv is doing an implicit cp && rm." when I wrote "mv -v ...". It copies first then removes all files at the end. What is profit of that? Can I switch it off, so it will transfer file by file, as you said - an atomic way?